# Convert column containing '.' in dataframe to dictonary

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to convert df to df1

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1], 'in.1': [8977], 'in.2': [8977], 'B': [
    {
        "C.i": 87387460,
        "C.j":233
}]})

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1], 'in':{'1': [8977], '2': [8977]}, 'B': [
    {"C":{
        "i": 87387460,
        "j":233}
}]})
```

I tried using recursive function but no luck.

My Code:

```
def convert_df(df):
    if df.shape[0] == 0:
        return []
    elif df.shape[0] == 1 and df.shape[1] == 1:
        return df.iloc[0, 0]
    elif df.shape[1] == 1:
        return [convert_df(pd.DataFrame(val)) for val in df[df.columns[0]].tolist()]
    else:
        return [{col_name: convert_df(pd.DataFrame(val)) for col_name, val in row.to_dict().items()} for i, row in df.iterrows()]
```

Comment: Maybe it will be better to change this before creating `df` dataframe? How do you build `df`?

Comment: Hmm..., on my Pandas 1.4.3, your definition on `df1` raises `ValueError: Mixing dicts with non-Series may lead to ambiguous ordering.`  and does not create the dataframe...

Comment: @Serge maybe `df1 = pd.DataFrame([{'A': 1, 'in': {'1': 8977, '2': 8977}, 'B': {'C': {'i': 87387460, 'j': 233}}}])`?

Answer (score 0):

To convert a column in a DataFrame that contains dots . in its name to a dictionary, you can do the following:

```
def convert_to_dict(df, col_name):
    out = {}
    for row in df[col_name].tolist():
        for key, val in row.items():
            sub_keys = key.split('.')
            d = out
            for sub_key in sub_keys[:-1]:
                if sub_key not in d:
                    d[sub_key] = {}
                d = d[sub_key]
            d[sub_keys[-1]] = val
    return out

col_name = 'B' 
df1 = convert_to_dict(df, col_name) 
df1 = pd.DataFrame({col_name: [df1]})
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The expected output is ambiguous, but I assume you might want to use [`to_dict`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html):

```
cols = list(df.filter(like='in'))

df1 = (df.drop(columns=cols)
         .assign(**{'in': pd.Series(df[cols].to_dict('index'))})
      )
```

Output:

```
   A                              B                            in
0  1  {'C.i': 87387460, 'C.j': 233}  {'in.1': 8977, 'in.2': 8977}
```